# iphone gsm call mute ringtone while in VoIP call

Tags: objective-c, ios, pjsip

is there any way to to mute or lower ringtone of a gsm call on iphone.

the problem is when someone has a voip call in progress and the gsm call comes thru, then one probably needs to see a physician. is there anyway to temporarily mute or lower the ringtone programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no way to change the ringtone volume programmatically til Apple reconsiders giving some freedom to the developers.